# Use Terminal as blackboard

Tags: bash, terminal

Time ago I've discovered a simple command line to turn the terminal window in a blackboard for just to take temporary notes. Talking about blackboard I doesn't mean nothing graphic, just alpha-numeric input. I don't remember that command anyway and hard googling didn't help me. Any help?

Comment: You mean graphical notes? Or do you wish them in a terminal?

Comment: What do you mean by blackboard? Do you expect to draw arbitrary shapes on it? Please [edit] your question and describe what you need in more detail.

Comment: @burian.vlastimil No graphic just terminal, in a passive no-command-intercept mode.

Comment: Would `nano` suffice?

Comment: @burian.vlastimil I don't want open any text editor, just cttrl-d to exit edit mode without salving/not-salving files and so concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `stty cbreak -echo; cat`, you can move around with arrows and clear the screen by typing `ESC [ 2 J`, set colors by typing other ANSI escape sequences, etc. Exit with ctrl-C. You may need to run `reset` or `stty sane` afterwards, it might be worthwhile to set up a script to do this if you need it often.

Comment: I'm just unable to clear the screen with `ESC [ 2 J`. Is that suggest correct? I'm missing something?

Comment: @Symb932 Works fine for me, what terminal are you using? Note that there are no spaces, and ESC is meant to be a literal escape character.

Comment: I've tried on both _Guake_ and _MATE Terminal 1.8.0_.

Answer (score 17):

Maybe `nano`? That's a text editor, so you can read and write text files with it, but it can also be used for what you describe.

There is also the option of clearing the terminal and keeping it blank, making it totally empty and letting you write whatever. Something like `reset; cat > /dev/null` would work. Note that you can not edit your "blackboard" this way, while with `nano` you can.

Comment: I agree with you. If a user wants to save his notes, `nano` is the best option. I also feel like this answer should have been accepted. You mentioned the method in the accepted answer first.

Comment: For a site which has a forum on user interface design, we then have a silly interface that does not show (easily) which reply was first. One need to hover the "answered H hours ago" line. Silly. Hope SE improves that.

Comment: @RolazaroAzeveires You can sort the answers by date, just below the question's comments on the right. Doesn't work to compare comments from two different answers though...

Comment: @Thomas: Oh... Thanks. Member for 3 years, read a few topics more than a third of those and... Looks like I am not as smart as I think (almost no one is... :-) I still say the UI is not good, while trying to be smart they eventually hide functionality. There is the shown rounded time - updated automatically! your comment changed from 1 to 2 hours in front of my eyes just now  - and there is a tool-tip, down to the exact second, I eventually forgot there is still another (3rd) way to see the time. Well... thank you for the hint and forgive me (all) for going off-topic on a comment

Answer (score 9):

What you are probably looking for is:

`reset; cat > /dev/null`

Comment: You can also save to a file by changing the `/dev/null` to some other filename.